# Create small buttons

Tags: html, css, button

I'm trying to make a button that's 11px by 11px, but it seems every browser I try has a minimum width of 12px for buttons (except IE9, which does 16px). Is there a way around this or do I need to use anchor tags?

**My CSS**

```
#testButton
{
    background-image: url(images/Sprites.png);
    width: 11px;
    height: 11px;
    border: 0 none transparent;
}
```

**The Result in IE**

[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting `padding: 0`?

Comment: can you give me jsfiddle?

Comment: Well, anchor tags are your best bet. If you want to stick with buttons you'll probably get a very messy workaround, if you use anchors, you don't need any special code. But have you tried using `!important` for the width and height rules?

Comment: @Selva [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/LEFUr/) a quick fiddle. You can inspect the button to see its size.

Comment: @CavynVonDeylen Your fiddle with padding:0; seems to work :) http://jsfiddle.net/MCV5t/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every browser has some default css. try using **[css reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)**

try adding  `padding` and `margin` to `0` in your button css

```
#testButton
{
    background-image: url(images/Sprites.png);
    width: 11px;
    height: 11px;
    border: 0 none transparent;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like all I needed was the padding:0. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so interesting question. I've been playing around [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mutahhir/dEt6w/). And I'm running Safari on a Mac here.

For me, this works (I think) on a simple `<button></button>` element:

```
button {
  width: 2px;
  height: 2px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 0;
  background: red;
}
```

I think the important thing to note is the `box-sizing` parameter. You can get more information about it [here](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/). Along with, of course, the `padding`​ style.